# "maintenance" page for Azure Static Website

Tags: azure, azure-storage

i have a static website hosted in Azure Storage Account and a CDN Endpoint with a custom domain (also in azure) directing to it. I need somehow show "maintenance page" when the site is "down"ish. I cant use 404 option because technically when there's a maintenance window the website is up. I only need this custom domain to redirect to the maintenance while the original url (https://{mydomain}.azureedge.net) provided by azure still works. Any advice please?